# Is the AC Method of Factoring polynomials more popular and used by teachers than others methods of factoring polynomials?

Tags: algebra, curriculum, tutoring, precalculus

This is an example of the AC Method:

$ x^2 + 16x +63 $

(1) $x² + 7x$ (2) $9x + 63$

(1) $x(x + 7)$ (2) $9(x + 7)$

so we have:
$x(x + 7)+ 9(x + 7)$

(1) with (2) The Result is:

$ (x+9)(x+7) $

I have more examples in letters:

[image]

Comparing for example with this list:

- Factoring out the GCF.
- The sum-product pattern.
- The grouping method.
- The perfect square trinomial pattern.
- The difference of squares pattern.
- Newton-Girard formulae

I don't know this Methods and is because I am not a native speaker maybe I know all of them just the language barrier...

Comment: Please include some actual *examples* in each case so we can see what these methods refer to. I have no idea what “AC method” or “sum-product pattern” mean, for instance.

Comment: I understand you. I also have terminology, synonyms and lang issues. I update the question and added 3 exercises for you check and compare.

Comment: Just curious... Why are you interested in popularity?

Comment: The different strategies you list are almost all useful in distinct situations. So: This question is kind of like asking which is more popular, a saw or a screwdriver. Both are needed for different use-cases; the workman lacking either is at disadvantage; popularity is a non-issue.

Comment: @FormerMath I want to be a tutor for english speakers. This method not exist in my language spanish if you research on internet. I am agree with you Daniel. maybe a good question were what are the different use-cases

Comment: The method exists, but it is just another realization of the classic factorization process. Indeed, $(x+A) (x+B) = x^2 + (A+B) x + AB$.